# If I assign a random number $r_x \in (0,1)$ to every $x \in (0,1)$ what are the odds that one of them will be a specific number?

Tags: probability, axiom-of-choice, random-functions

I'll start by motivating by question with a simpler scenario to ensure I've at least understood that scenario properly.

---

Scenario 1 :

Imagine an infinite sequence of numbers where $i$ is the $i^{th}$ element of that sequence. If I assign a random number $r_i \in (0,1)$ to each $i$, and then ask "What are the odds that for at least one $i$ we have $r_i = a$ ?" where $a$ is some specific pre-chosen number in $(0,1)$ (say $0.5$), I believe I am correct in assuming that such an $i$ will almost never exist because $\aleph_0 = |\mathbb{N}| < |(0,1)| = \mathfrak{c}$. Is this reasoning accurate ?

---

Scenario 2 :

So now I would like to consider another infinite set of random numbers, but this time I'd like to replace my discrete infinite sequence with a sort of continuous equivalent, which I suppose is somewhat similar to a random function. Namely, for every real number in $x \in (0,1)$ I associate a random number $r_x \in (0,1)$. Now I again ask the question "What are the odds that for some $x$ we have $r_x = a$ ?". Here I'm really not sure what to think. It's certainly possible that the very scenario I'm describing cannot be rigorously defined and no such set of $r_x$ can exist, in which case I'd appreciate an explanation as to why this is so and what the closest possible scenario is. Conversely, feel free to more rigorously define my problem.

---

Michael provided a solution to a seemingly related problem that's somewhere in between scenario 1 and 2 and so I'll post it here to see if anyone can extend this type of thinking to the reals :

1) Choose some natural number $n$

2) List the naturals from $1$ to $n$ (let's call this set $\mathbb{N}_n$)

3) For each number in $\mathbb{N}_n$ randomly assign another number in $\mathbb{N}_n$

We can then see that the probability that some randomly chosen number $a \in \mathbb{N}$ never appears is $(1-1/n)^n$, which approaches $1/e$ as $n\to\infty$.  The chance that it does appear therefore approaches $1-1/e=0.632$.

Is there any way to extend this to all reals between $0$ and $1$ ?

---

After a little digging, I've come to think that perhaps there can't be an answer to my question, or if there is I'm probably in way over my head trying to find one. Let's define the problem a little more rigorously first :

1) Consider the family of sets $S_x$ where $S_x = (0,1) \forall x \in (0,1)$ (yes these are all the same set, why I'm considering this family will become apparent in step 2).

2) Using the axiom of choice, construct a set $R$ which contains one randomly chosen element from each $S_x$. This set $R$ is non-measurable.

3) Pick some number $a \in (0,1)$, and ask what are the odds that $a \in R$ is true ?

And now I'm simply not sure what to make of the fact that $R$ is non-measurable. Does it make my question unanswerable ? Or does it actually provide a great test case for understanding non-measurable sets ?

Comment: Why is this tagged [axiom-of-choice] again?

Comment: @Asaf I added the tag after my final edit made an argument using it.

Comment: I see that you're also using quantifiers and inference rules. Why not add [quantifiers] and [logic] too? :-) The AC tag is for questions which ask about the specific role of the axiom in the proof, and so on. Not for questions which just happen to invoke it.

Comment: @Asaf Well I actually quite curious about the specific implications of using AC here, since I want to know what to make of non-measurability when making cardinality based arguments. Non-measurability is a fundamental aspect of using AC is it not ?

Comment: I don't quite see why $R$ is non-measurable. Just because you invoke the axiom of choice doesn't mean automatically the set is non-measurable. What if $R=(0,1)$ again since you just chose $x$ from $S_x$?

Comment: @Asaf Good point. This isn't my field at all so I'm just developing my train of thought in the hope that someone will set me straight and provide an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a finite version of Scenario 1:
* List the rational numbers in $(0,1)$.
* Pick a large number $n$
* For each of the first $n$ numbers, associate one of the first $n$ numbers.
The probability that one of the first $n$ numbers never appears is $(1-1/n)^n$, which approaches $1/e$ as $n\to\infty$.  The chance that it does appear approaches $1-1/e=0.632$

Comment: That's certainly interesting and a result I wouldn't have expected. Does this mean that of all infinite sequences of natural numbers, only 63% will contain a given number ?

Comment: I'll stay in the finite world.  Once infinity appears, you have to tread carefully.

Comment: Yes I realize that, which is why I was hoping a more enlightened individual like yourself would give me treading tips ;) Maybe next time.

Comment: This is surely the analysis that occurs to me first, but I'm not wholly convinced one can do this on the uncountable $(0, 1)$.  Is this in fact certain?

Comment: @Brian I don't think he's claiming this applies to the uncountables, just pointing out how to solve a somewhat related problem.

Comment: @ticster: Yes, you're quite right.  Does anyone know whether we need AC for this, or does the imposition of a particular distribution over $(0, 1)$ obviate that?

Comment: One thing I don't understand is why you chose the rational numbers instead of the naturals. I mean it's the same result but it's easier to understand it that way. In fact your third step is just a mapping to get around the fact that you used the rationals instead of the naturals.